# IELTS score in which section of my cv?

Tags: cv, language-exams

Where should I put my IELTS score? Under certifications or in the language section where I include my native language and English?

My overall is 8.0, and I scored 9.0 in reading and 8.5 in listening. Do you think I should add the score of each skill or just the overall?

I want to use this CV to find a supervisor for applying for a master's degree.

Comment: Yes, the language section would be more appropriate as an IELTS score is not a certification.